# JQuery and Draggable, when the mouse is too fast the the move of the object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an `IFrame` within a `div`, I use JQuery's Draggable to activate the outer div draggability.  My problem is when I drag too fast the mouse (so the mouse pointer is is not synchronized with the Drag Start point) and the pointer go inside the `IFrame`, the dragbility donsn't work anymore.

Does any one have a solution?

Thanks